# Removing an element from an Array in java

Tags: java, arrays

So I am in the AP Computer Science class in High School so I'm not very experienced. I have a program to do that requires me to read in numbers from a file, put those numbers into an array and then remove all of the 0's from the array.

So if the numbers are: 0,2,4,6,0,5,3,5...
I would need to create an array: [0,2,4,6,0,5,3,5]
and then remove the 0's: [2,4,6,5,3,5]

I have to do this using arrays and I am not allowed to create a second array to do this. I have looked all over online and the Java API's to find a method that can remove an element from an array but I simply can't find one. If somebody has any idea of one that I can use or a direction to steer me in, your advice would be much appreciated.

THIS IS THE QUESTION WORD FOR WORD:
1. Write a program that reads a text file(compact.txt) and stores the integers in an array. Your instructor will provide this text file.
2. Write a method *compact* that removes all zeroes from the array, leaving the order of the elements unchanged. All local variables within this function must be scalar. In other words, you may not use a second array to solve the problem. 
3. Do not solve the problem simply by printing out only the non-zero values in the array. The *compact* method must remove all zeroes from the array.

Comment: Is it allowed to use `ArrayList`?

Comment: It says specifically for me not to use ArrayList that is the annoying part! @Christian

Comment: Arrays are size-fixed in Java. If your array has length `4`, you cannot delete elements and make it length `2`.

Comment: That is exactly what i told my teacher because that fact seems to make this impossible to do, but he insists that it is possible. @Christian

Comment: Do you have to put the zeros into the array in the first place? Because an array is of a fixed size you can't just remove something from it.

Comment: Are you asking if I can simply read the numbers from the file, and if the read number is 0, simply go to the next number without putting it into the Array? @Eluvatar

Comment: You can't do it without creating a new array, arrays are immutable with regards to length. You can't shrink or grow an array.

Comment: @user3164008 is it possible you're understanding the question wrong? Can you add the actual question to your question here? Sometimes its difficult to know what is being asked if you're not experienced enough with the subject.

Comment: Any solution will require a second array which is `n` number of elements shorter than the first by the number if `0`s in the first...

Comment: That is what I think. I will talk to my teacher tomorrow since I have now researched and not found a single method. He might have figured this out a different way but simply forgot to tell us.

Comment: @user3164008 Where does it specifically say you can't use `ArrayList`? Please post your entire question as your teacher asked!

Comment: I went to my teacher asking if we could use ArrayList and he specifically told the entire class to use nothing but Array. This was not in the instructions.

Comment: Your instructor doesn't know Java. He asks you to create a `method` called compact, and then later says: this `function`. Tsk tsk tsk

Comment: Are you sure "scalar" means "non-array"? Are you sure this is in "Java"?

Comment: Trust me guys, if I knew we could use ArrayList, there would be no problem. That would be extremely easy. Like I said before, I will talk to my teacher tomorrow and I will edit my post on any updates.

Comment: @NicolásCarlo this is from the Java Curriculum lab assignment. My instructor had nothing to do with writing this assignment. He has taught this class for 38 years, he as a matter of fact, does know Java.

Comment: @user3164008 He has taught a Java class for 38 years? Are you interested in buying Florida real estate?

Comment: @user3164008 I was only kidding but back to the subject. If the guy knows what he's talking about then I would chalk this up as a trick question. You are not allowed to create another array or an ArrayList. You are not allowed to skip the 0's when reading the file. You are not allowed to replace the 0's with another value. The only thing left to ask is whether you're allowed magic or not.

Comment: Hey I thought java first released on 1995. How he could teaching that for 38 years.
1995+38 = 2033

Comment: I think the guy meant he's been teaching the computer science class for 38 years, AND he knows Java too.

Comment: @BRjava [Oak](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oak_%28programming_language%29) was 1991. So, assuming he's like James Gosling's BFF that's only 2029.

Answer (score 2):

You could try the following: Since you cannot modify the length of the array, you can arrange it so you put all zeroes at the end of the array and with value `-1` (this is optional, just to indicate they are zeroes).

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int[] arr = { 0, 1, 2, 0, 3, 0, 4, 0, 5, 6, 7 };
    int[] arrWithoutZeros = compact(arr);
    for (int i : arrWithoutZeros) {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}

private static int[] compact(int[] arr)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] == 0) {
            int j = 0;
            for (j = i; j < arr.length - 1; j++) {
                arr[j] = arr[j + 1];
            }
            arr[j] = -1;
            i--;
        }

    }
    return arr;
}
```

**Output:**

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
-1
-1
-1
-1
```

**Note:** This meets the question requirements:

- Leaves the order of elements unchanged (it changes its position, but not the order)
- Don't use a second array
- Not solved by just printing the non-zero elements
- Removes zeros from array (they are now `-1`)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not normally a fan of doing homework, but I found this one interesting and impossible as written, so here goes.

This is much like Christian's answer, but I'm using Integer instead of int so that I can set the 0s to null instead of some other integer.  I've also avoided the extra loop he has to copy every remaining value down on every single 0, instead iterating the array once and then iterating the tail only once to set the null values.

```
public class ArrayCompact {

private static Integer[] ARRAY = { 1, 3, 5, 0, 7, 9, 0, 2, 0, 4, 6, 0, 8, -1, 0 };

public static void main( String[] args ) {
    printArray( compact(ARRAY ));
}

public static Integer[] compact( Integer[] ints ) {
    int j = 0;
    for ( int i = 0; i < ints.length; i++ ) {
        if ( ints[i] != 0 ) {
            ints[j++] = ints[i];
        }
    }
    for ( int i = j; i < ints.length; i++ ) {
        ints[i] = null;
    }
    return ints;
}

public static void printArray( Integer[] ints ) {
    for ( Integer i : ints ) {
        System.out.print( i + " " );
    }
}
}
```

Output `1 3 5 7 9 2 4 6 8 -1 null null null null null` Technically I guess you could just not print the nulls, since that's not not printing 0s...

Answer (score 1):

Another Edit:

(I think previous answer is still meaningful and I am keeping it at the end.  This edit is mainly for suggestion specific to the homework requirement)

Base on the question, the compact logic treat 0 as something that is "meaningless" and need to be "removed".  Therefore we don't really need some kind of special value after we "shrink" the array.  Simply keeping it as 0 will help.

Apart from the "copy [i+1,end] to i" method, there is another (easier and possibly faster) method that you can do to "remove" the zeros.

Basically what you need is, iterate through the array.  If you encounter a 0, then find the first non-zero value after that position, and swap the zero with that non-zero value.

Which looks like this in psuedo code:

```
for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  if (arr[i] == 0) {
    for (j = i+1; j < arr.length; j++) {
       if (arr[j] != 0) {
         arr[i] = arr[j];
         arr[j] = 0;
         break;
       }
    }
  }
}
// arr is "shrinked" here
```

Then it is your choice to return an actually shrinked copy of array, or simply return the "so-called-shrinked" array with 0s at the end.

---

Something for you to think of:

First, in Java, size of array is fixed, therefore, it is not possible to shrink array's size.  Therefore, it is IMPOSSIBLE to have a result array with less elements without creating a new array

If it is fine for you to leave unused element at the end as some special values (e.g. -ve, or 0 etc), the removing element at position `i` from array essentially means:

copy array elements [i+1 to end] to position i, and replace arr[end] with special empty value

e.g. [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]

If I want to remove index 2, what I need to do is to copy element 3-4 to position 2:

```
[1,3,5,7,9]   ->  [1,3,7,9,9]
       ^^^             ^^^
```

and replace end element with some special value (e.g. -1 in this example):

```
[1,3,7,9,9] -> [1,3,5,7,-1]
```

Array copy can be done easily by using `System.arrayCopy()`

---

Have just seen update in your question.

Most of my answer is still valid, and here is some extra update with regards to your question:

1. If you are sure that no Integer.MIN will appear in your input, then use my above mentioned approach, and update the input array accordingly.
2. You may consider using Integer[] instead of int[], so that you can put null
3. This is the most "normal" approach, but given your requirement, this may or may not be valid.  The question ask you to have only scalar LOCAL VARIABLES.  Which implies to me that, if I don't create another variable, I can still return another array (seems that the question is only trying to stop you using another array in process of compacting).  Just follow what I have mentioned above, however, instead of replacing the end position with some special value, just keep a local var which is array length.  Whenever you remove an element (by copying [i+1, 0] to position i), decrement the array length var.  At the end, return a new copy of "shrinked" array by using `Arrays.copyOf(oldArray, newLength)`.

Here is a piece of psuedo-code for point 3:

```
int[] compact(int[] input) {
  int arrSize = input.length;

  int i = 0;
  while (i < arrSize) {
    if (input[i] == 0) {
      copy input[i+1 to end] to input[i to end-1]
      arrSize--;
    } else {
      i++;
    }
  }
  return Arrays.copyOf(input, arrSize);
}
```